# Raycast два луча левее и правее основного

Tags: c#, unity3d, математика, разработка-игр, геометрия

Пускается луч из точки `selfPosition` в направлении `direction` через `Raycast`. Как можно пустить ещё один луч чуть левее (на несколько градусов против часовой стрелки от основного луча), а другой чуть правее (на несколько градусов по часовой стрелке от основного луча)

`Physics2D.RaycastAll(selfPosition, direction);`

Comment: Что бы получить одно направление, относительно другого, нужно перемножить их кватернионы. Если говорить о "лево" и "право", то нужно понимать относительно чего? Для нас привычно относительно оси Vector3.up, но объекты в юнити не редко повёрнуты по разным осям и их локальный up куда только не направлен. Кватернионы вектора можно просто повернуть на заданное значение относительно заданной оси, есть у него такие методы. Но если это глобальный up, можно и самому посчитать, это просто вычисление радианы вектора x-z и точка на окружности, это обязан уметь делать любой программист в геймдеве.

Comment: я же пояснил, что лево и право - против часовой стрелки и по